# Jquery - each - return independent values

Tags: jquery

I have a grid of product of which I want to iterate through and create a new variable per div, called discount.

The problem I am experiencing is being able to independently access each of the divs, and run the operation to get the discount percentage. At the moment my output is every percentage discount listed under every product, rather then that specific div's discount value.

I think I need to alter the each function, though I am unsure as to the next step.

```
<div class="product">
<div class="text">
<span class="red">60</span>
<span class="grey">100</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="product">
<div class="text">
<span class="red">40</span>
<span class="grey">100</span>
</div>
</div>

$('.product').each(function() {
    var org = $(this).find(".text .grey").html().replace("$","").replace("WAS","");
    var nwp = $(this).find('.text .red').html().replace("$","").replace("WAS","");
    var OrigPrice = parseFloat(org);
    var NewPrice = parseFloat(nwp);
    var discount = ((((NewPrice/OrigPrice)-1)*-1)*100).toFixed(0);
    $('<p>' + discount +' % off </p>').insertAfter('.grey');

});
```

Current output

```
<div class="product">
<div class="text">
<span class="red">60</span>
<span class="grey">100</span>
<p>"40 % off"</p>
<p>"60 % off"</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="product">
<div class="text">
<span class="red">40</span>
<span class="grey">100</span>
<p>"40 % off"</p>
<p>"60 % off"</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$(this)` in your `insertAfter()` call, so it only adds to the current DIV. Just like you do when you're getting the input values in `org` and `nwp`.

```
$('<p>' + discount +' % off </p>').insertAfter($(this).find('.text .grey'));
```

Comment: Perfect. I think I was just looking at the problem for too long and got lost.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `.insertAfter('.gray')` you're telling jQuery to look for all elements inside the DOM containing the `gray` class.
Meaning, for each product you are looking for ALL elements with the gray class and add your new `<p>` element.
If you have N products, you will get N discounts.

What you want is to find the gray class element INSIDE of the product:

```
$(this).find('.gray').after('<p>...</p>');
```

Alternatively, you can ignore the gray class and append your new element as the last child of product:

```
$(this).append('<p>...</p>');
```

Side note:

Have you considered any two way binding framework (e.g. Angular)?

Comment: If he does `$(this).append()` it will put it outside the `<div class="text">`